# why is the browser following URL that is updated by pushState()?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have made a simple ASP.NET MVC application that is updating the page contents using AJAX and updating the URL using history.pushState() on click event on a button. Here is the code

```
$("#btn").click(function (event) {
    var Response = CallAPI();
    var PageTitle = $(document).find("title").text();
    var StateObj = {
        FirstName: Response.FirstName
    };
    var FirstNameUrl = "/" + Response.FirstName;
    history.pushState( StateObj, PageTitle + Response.FirstName, "/Users" + FirstNameUrl );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The url at the beginning is `http://localhost:64061/Users` and after the ajax request, the url is updated to `http://localhost:64061/Users/UserName` however this URL does not exist, which is the problem because as i refresh it says document does not exist, however i have used `event.preventDefaults()`.

I know it is because the url doesn't map to any existing route but does that mean i have to define a route for this url as well? Is it the right way?

Comment: Did you try to preventDefault first? (maybe put it before the second line)

Comment: Yes i tried it, even tried putting `preventDefault()` on both the start and the end, but didn't worked either.

Comment: Which browser do you use? It is not the expected behavior. Btw. does it work without the API request? Is response defined?

Comment: Might be that Response is undefined and then Response.FirstName will throw an error...and the browser will ignore the rest of your javascript and and just follow the href of #btn.

Comment: I tried without API call as well, still the same result, and yes response is defined, the complete code would be a bit out of context and time taking to understand, just for the idea `CallAPI()` is returning the Response object which is populated and correctly modifies the URL, but still seems to follow the URL.

Comment: What happens if you write `history.pushState({}, "Page title", "/Users");` in your browser console?

Comment: Its updating the URL to `http://localhost:64061/Users/Users` which is still not a defined URL, so it still says document not found.

Comment: So it really follows the link? Then there might be an error in interpreting JavaScript the right way... What is your browser. It just should change the url without following the link!

Comment: Maybe I totally misunderstood you....of course you need a route! Or at least a catch all route.

Comment: Its Google Chrome version: 69.0.3497.100.

Comment: Ok, your last two questions are confusing.....are you looking for availability of those pages or are you wondering why your browser follows the link?

Answer (score 0):

`history.pushState` is just working frontend-wise. It won’t care if the document really exists. This is in charge of the backend.

You could provide a catch-all route with an regex like: `/\/Users\/\w+$/`

For ASP.NET MVC explicit it should be something like `/Users/{userName}`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs